# how to call javascript client side function from code behind file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How would I call showItems() function in aspx page from code behind.

```
<script>
function getItems(){
  var items = [];
  return items; //items=['a','b','c']
}
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Hiddenfield id="HiddenField1" runat="server"></asp:hiddenfield>
</form>
```

code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "items", "<script type='text/javascript'>getItems()</script>", false);
```

Comment: javascript can't call code behind functions directly.

Answer (score 4):

A few things here...

**First**, you don't "call a client-side function from server-side code."  What you *can* do is include some client-side code which itself will call the function, client-side.  Which *appears* to be what you're doing, but I just want to make sure you understand the difference.

**Second**, your function is called `showItems`, but you're calling a function called `getItems`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>getItems()</script>
```

Call `showItems()` instead?  Like this?:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "items", "<script type='text/javascript'>showItems()</script>", false);
```

**Third**, the `showItems` function returns something.  But you're not actually *doing anything* with that result.  You're simply invoking the function and ignoring the result.  So it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the items, how would I store that in a variable?

Comment: @sheelachen: In JavaScript: `var items = showItems();`  Then in any JavaScript code for which `items` is in scope you can use that variable.  It works very similarly to C# or, well, just about any other language.  When a function returns a value, you store that value in a variable when calling the function.

Comment: :so how would I retrieve those items in code behind?

Comment: @sheelachen: Well, you don't.  By the time the JavaScript code executes, the page has already rendered client-side.  You can send those values to the server with an AJAX call, and the server would need something to handle that call.  (Web Methods might be the current WebForms way of doing that?)  It sounds like you're misunderstanding some fundamental concepts of web development here, namely that server-side and client-side code don't interact.

Comment: thnks David for clarification. can hidden fields be used to pass it to server side?

Comment: @sheelachen: In the context of a form post to the server, sure.  You can set the value to a hidden field and retrieve it server-side.  Note that this will limit the value to a `string`, so if it's a more complex structure then you'd need to serialize it to a string in client-side code and de-serialize it in server-side code.  It's not clear what your actual goal is here, you're only showing us a very small piece of a larger puzzle that you don't seem to fully understand, so there's no way to recommend a best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "showItems();", true);
```

**Edit**: To get the javascript return value at C# code behind Assign the values to the hidden control using the javascript code. Then you can access the Hidden control value in C# code. Take a look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/how-to-return-value-from-javascript-to-server-side/) article. for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showItems() {
        var items = new Array(3);
        items[0] = "name1";
        items[1] = "name2";
        items[2] = "name3";
        items[3] = "name4";

        document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = items.join(',');
    }
</script>
```

And in the code behind:

```
string[] itemArr = HiddenField1.Value.Split(",".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: user2946329:so basically I need to store the returned array(items) in hidden fields and access it in code behind, correct?

Comment: user2946329 if items is already an array, as I have edited, should I used JSON.stringify(items)?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it is now what you were looking for..please try it and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: user2946329 I am getting some errors, I have edited my html, could you please take a look?

Comment: it says the name 'hiddenfield1' does not exist in current context.

Comment: after adding <runat="server">, I am still getting, uncaught typeerror: cannot set property 'value' of null.

Comment: Did you add this line `document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = items.join(',');` instead of `return items;`?

Comment: yes, that's what i did. it looks like it can't find id 'hiddenfield1'

Comment: write this line `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "showItems();", true);` in the `Page_Load` and this line:`string[] itemArr = HiddenField1.Value.Split(",".ToCharArray());` in the `Button_Click`

Comment: i had to use JSON.stringify(items) to store in hidden field. it worked finally. now, i am trying to retrieve it in server side.

Comment: thnks for all the help. i am still unable to retrieve items in the server side.

Comment: I think you missed something. I have tested this in my environment and it worked perfect. Anyway good luck. :)